# use distinctUntilChanged on objects

Tags: javascript, rxjs

How can I have `distinctUntilChanged` work with objects like this

```
myObs = Observable.from([{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}]);

myObs.distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(value => {
  // I only want to receive {foo: 'bar'} once
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass a function inside the `distinctUntilChanged` that returns a boolean to make sure that the objects are the same.

Example

```
    myObs. distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a.foo === b.foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`distinctUntilKeyChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilkeychanged) if you want to compare based on an object property.

```
myObs.distinctUntilKeyChanged('foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

`distinctUntilChanged` takes a function comparator argument, since the default is to compare using `===` equality (which is always different for different object references):

```
// compare by .foo which is a primitive
myObs.distinctUntilChanged((x,y) => y.foo === x.foo) 
.subscribe(value => {
  // receive {foo: 'bar'} once
});
```